# Canvas + JQM doesn't work together?

Tags: html, video, canvas, jquery-mobile

Has anyone tried to use `HTML canvas` together with `jQuery Mobile`? I have been following this guide http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ to get the video background for my website. However as soon as I use the script includes for `JQM` the background video fails. Is there perhaps a way that allows me to only load the `JQM` files for the parts that require `JQM`?

Comment: HTML5 canvas will definitely work with JQM. Post your code Or fiddle it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JzBSv/ As soon as I add the jquery-mobile scripts it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JzBSv/1/)

wrap your code inside

```
<div data-role="page">
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle works, but it does not work whenever I try it on my own server. Still crashes from the <script> tags.

Comment: I am really clueless about your problem now. But JQM with canvas / video won't break. My fiddle is better example.

Comment: Yeah, prolly some syntax error somewhere that I can't find or anything. Will try again from scratch, and hopefully it'll work then. :) Cheers for ur help.